# Running sklearns label encoder on all columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

[Image of ull error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x707U.png)

I am trying to run `LabelEncoder` on all columns that are of type object. This is the code I wrote but it throws this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
le=LabelEncoder()
for col in X_test.columns.values:
    if X_test[col].dtypes=='object':
        data=X_train[col].append(X_test[col])
        le.fit(data.values)
        X_train[col]=le.transform(X_train[col])
        X_test[col]=le.transform(X_test[col])
```

Comment: Can you post more details of error? which line caused error?

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE ive added a screensho of the full error

Comment: data=(X_train[col].append(X_test[col])).astype(str)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it has different types while appending.  You try converting all to `str` at fit method:

```
le.fit(data.values.astype(str))
```

And you have to change your data type to `str` for `transform` as well since the classes in `LabelEncoder` will be `str`:

```
X_train[col]=le.transform(X_train[col].astype(str))
X_test[col]=le.transform(X_test[col].astype(str))
```

Trying to recreate similar problem. If dataframe has values with `int` and `str`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["tokyo", 1 , "paris"]})
print(df)
```

Result:

```
    col1
0  tokyo
1      1
2  paris
```

Now, using `Labelenconder` would give similar error message i.e. `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()` :

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.col1.values)
```

Converting all to `str` in fit or before may resolve issue:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.col1.values.astype(str))
print(le.classes_)
```

Result:

```
['1' 'paris' 'tokyo']
```

If you just call `le.transform(df.col1)`, it will throw similar error again.

So, it has to be `le.transform(df.col1.astype(str))` instead.

Comment: Very nice and detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error is basically telling you the exact problem: some of the values are strings and some are not. You can solve this by calling `c.astype(str)` each time you call `fit`, `fit_transform`, or `transform`, on Series `c`, e.g.:

```
le.fit(data.values.astype(str))
```

Comment: @Jack.Wol You're very welcome. I suggest you accept OpenSource's answer, which is very nice and detailed.